# Frobenius norm equality related to orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $k > 1$. For which $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ with $\Vert v_i \Vert = 1$ holds the following equation
$$
\left\Vert \prod_{i=1}^k v_i v_i^T \right\Vert_F = \left\Vert \prod_{i=1}^k (I - v_i v_i^T) \right\Vert_F,
$$
where $\Vert \Vert_F$ indicates the Frobenius norm and $I$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: A Householder reflection has the form $I-\color{red}2 VV^T$

Comment: @JeanMarie I am aware of this. However, this is no typo. The original problem is derived from a Householder matrix. Maybe at this point, its not a good name anymore, I agree.

Comment: $I-VV^T$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the hyperplane with normal vector $V$, whereas $VV^T$ (rank one matrix) is the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto vector $V$.

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for the explanation. I changed the title accordingly.

Comment: The first product $v_1(v_1^Tv_2)(v_2^Tv_3)( \cdots v_n)v_n^T$ can be simplified into $k v_1v_n^T$ for a certain real $k$, but after that ...

Comment: @JeanMarie right, and $k \leq 1$

Comment: Somewhat related : https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82393275.pdf

Comment: Your conditions are really restrictive... e.g. for $k = 1$ we require that $\|v_1v_1^{T}\|_F = \|(I - v_1v_1^T)\|_F$. The only way this would work is if $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_1(i)^2} = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (1 - v_1(i)^2)^2}$ or equivalently $n= 2\sum_{i=1}^n v_1(i)^2 = 2$. You probably don't want $n$ to be fixed, right?